# SQL; How can I use Where Condition for only one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

First of all,

```
Select Count(*)
From PROSPECT_MASTER //Result:12730 row


Select Count(*)
From YAZ..MARDATA.S_MUSTERI // Result: 1112 row
```

And this is my query;

```
SELECT a.ID, a.TURQ_ID, a.UNVAN, a.TIP, a.AKTOR, 
       a.GSM_ALAN, a.GSM_TEL, a.IS_ALAN, a.IS_TEL, 
       a.IS_EXT, a.EV_ALAN, a.EV_TEL, a.ADRES, 
       a.STF_KONTAK, 
       (CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL
         THEN (B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2) 
         ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES END) 
       COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS YAZ_ADRES , A.SEHIR, A.PS, A.MEMO
FROM PROSPECT_MASTER A, YAZ..MARDATA.S_MUSTERI B
WHERE A.ID IN (B.TC_KIM_NO, B.VERGI_NO) // Result 1070 row
```

As normally, `A.ID IN (B.TC_KIM_NO, B.VERGI_NO)` condition is working with on my full query, but I want this condition will works only one column (YAZ_ADRES) because  **A.ID** doesn't has  all **B.TC_KIM_NO** or all **B.VERGI_NO**

My query should get 12730 row like count of `PROSPECT_MASTER` table. But I want to run `A.ID IN (B.TC_KIM_NO, B.VERGI_NO)` condition only for `YAZ_ADRES` column.

How can I do that ?

Comment: WHERE A.ID IN (B.TC_KIM_NO) or A.ID IN (B.VERGI_NO)

Comment: @Preet Sangha - isn't  `a in (b,c)` equivalent to `a in (b) or a in (c)`. It seems to me that `a in (b,c) or b is null or c is null` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you need is an outer join?

```
SELECT a.ID, a.TURQ_ID, a.UNVAN, a.TIP, a.AKTOR, 
       a.GSM_ALAN, a.GSM_TEL, a.IS_ALAN, a.IS_TEL, 
       a.IS_EXT, a.EV_ALAN, a.EV_TEL, a.ADRES, 
       a.STF_KONTAK, 
       (CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL
         THEN (B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2) 
         ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES END) 
       COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS YAZ_ADRES , A.SEHIR, A.PS, A.MEMO
FROM PROSPECT_MASTER A
LEFT OUTER JOIN YAZ..MARDATA.S_MUSTERI B
ON A.ID IN (B.TC_KIM_NO, B.VERGI_NO) // Result 12730 rows
```

Comment: It works but this query getting 12733 row. Isn't that weird ?

Comment: That suggests that in a few cases there is more than one B record matching the A record.